# Does OpenMP need -Ofast to run properly?

Tags: c, openmp

Hello i am trying to learn openMP and i am confused by the results, i have **pi.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <omp.h>
#define NUM_THREADS 6

static long num_steps = 1000000000;
double step;

int main(){

    int i, nthreads; double pi, sum[NUM_THREADS];
    step = 1.0/(double)num_steps;
    double start_time, run_time;
    omp_set_num_threads(NUM_THREADS);
    start_time = omp_get_wtime();
    #pragma omp parallel
    {
        int i, id, nthrds; double x;
        id = omp_get_thread_num();
        nthrds = omp_get_num_threads();
        if(id == 0) nthreads = nthrds;
        for(i = id, sum[id] = 0.0; i < num_steps; i+=nthrds){
            x = (i+0.5)*step;
            sum[id] +=  4.0 / (1.0+x*x);
        }
    }
    for(i = 0, pi = 0.0; i < nthreads; i++){
        pi += step * sum[i];
    }
    run_time = omp_get_wtime();
    printf("[PI %f TIME %.4fs ON %d THREADS]\n", pi, (run_time - start_time), nthreads);

}
```

and when i complile with `gcc -fopenmp -Wall -Wextra pi.c` i get these results:

```
[PI 3.141593 TIME 3.8663s ON 1 THREADS]
[PI 3.141593 TIME 7.9291s ON 2 THREADS]
[PI 3.141593 TIME 8.4961s ON 3 THREADS]
[PI 3.141593 TIME 10.8343s ON 4 THREADS]
[PI 3.141593 TIME 9.7167s ON 5 THREADS]
[PI 3.141593 TIME 10.0182s ON 6 THREADS]
```

but when i compile with `gcc -fopenmp -Ofast -Wall -Wextra pi.c` i get the results i expected:

```
[PI 3.141593 TIME 1.8380s ON 1 THREADS]
[PI 3.141593 TIME 0.7553s ON 2 THREADS]
[PI 3.141593 TIME 0.5525s ON 3 THREADS]
[PI 3.141593 TIME 0.3930s ON 4 THREADS]
[PI 3.141593 TIME 0.3694s ON 5 THREADS]
[PI 3.141593 TIME 0.3287s ON 6 THREADS]
```

`-O2,-O3` behave similarly to `-Ofast` and `-O1` has results similar to without compiler optimizations, with more threads giving worse results.

Comment: Use a local variable in the `for` loop, and after it assign its value to `sum[id]` otherwise you have false sharing.

Comment: One should always benchmark using release builds and release builds always use at least `-O2`. `-O3` can significantly increase binary size, but still is often used. `-Ofast` should only be used if you know its implications (especially considering floating point math), as it could change the results of calculations.

Comment: For numerical computations that haven't been carefully analyzed, `-O3 -march=native` is often a good choice.  It turns on the aggressive loop optimizations (unrolling, vectorization) that are valuable mainly for computational kernels, and it directs the compiler to tune for the exact machine you're running it on, but it does _not_ do anything that could change the results of the calculatIon.

Comment: Isn't 'i' local already? Also you mean i should initialize 'sum[id]' with 'i'? How does this prevent false sharing? @Laci

Comment: In this case '-Ofast' doesn't change the result though(note taken about using it carefully), also my question was mainly about compiling without any optimizations and getting those weird results @paleonix

Comment: The result scale only with `-O2`/`-O3`/`-Ofast` because `sum[id]` is optimized to a local SSE SIMD register and thus you do not pay the cost of *false sharing* anymore. The false sharing on `sum` cause a cache line bouncing which almost serialize the whole execution (while adding a pretty big latency). Note that GCC is not able to vectorize the loop and use the inefficient divsd instruction. You can use reciprocal instructions to get much faster results at the expense of a lower accuracy. Note also that this formula is pretty slow to compute Pi efficiently.

Comment: Thank you @JérômeRichard this is the answer to my main question, i am very new to these concepts and this is how far i have reached with openMP, so stuff like padding or using other openMP tools to avoid false sharing are to be learned. Also this formula for Pi is from this series i am following [Introduction to OpenMP - Tim Mattson (Intel)](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLLX-Q6B8xqZ8n8bwjGdzBJ25X2utwnoEG), so it's use is purely educational.

Comment: @Grapejuice123 Benchmarking without optimizations is pretty much meaningless. If the context is that your debug code runs to slow to debug it, one would also try to get rid of the false sharing and maybe try `-Og`. But in your context not using optimization is just not reasonable.

Comment: @Grapejuice123 Even if your result doesn't change right now, `-O3` is just a more sane default. You never know when you will reuse code (e.g. a Makefile) and then either hunt the reason for the wrong results or - even worse - don't notice the wrong results at all. As you said that `-O3` scales well, there is no reason to risk anything.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: No, you don't need `Ofast` to run omp properly.

If you do `man gcc`, you can see

> ```
>    -Ofast
>        Disregard strict standards compliance.  -Ofast enables all -O3 optimizations.
>        It also enables optimizations that are not valid for all standard-compliant
>        programs.  It turns on -ffast-math and the Fortran-specific
>        -fno-protect-parens and -fstack-arrays.
> ```

So basically, `Ofast` turns on `O3` optimisations + other optimisations and hence faster.

If you check `-ffast-math` (set by `Ofast`) in manual, you can see:

```
   -ffast-math
       This option causes the preprocessor macro "__FAST_MATH__" to be defined.

       This option is not turned on by any -O option besides -Ofast since it can
       result in incorrect output for programs that depend on an exact implementation
       of IEEE or ISO rules/specifications for math functions. It may, however, yield
       faster code for programs that do not require the guarantees of these
       specifications.
```

Key point here is *Ofast disregard strict standards compliance.* and *it can result in incorrect output for programs that depend on an exact implementation of IEEE or ISO rules/specifications for math functions* (which is also mentioned in the comments)

So to summarize, `Ofast` can give you faster results if you don't care about the standard compliance or [catastrophic cancellation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catastrophic_cancellation) (as mentioned by **zwol** in comments) or there could be others that I don't know..

Comment: In this case pi returns 3.141593 which is valid so '-Ofast' isn't a problem, my problem is why without '-O2 -O3 -Ofast' i don't get the expected runtime that i get say with '-Ofast'.

Comment: "if you don't care about the standard compliance" understates the potential problems.  `-Ofast` enables `-fassociative-math` which can introduce [catastrophic cancellation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catastrophic_cancellation) to programs that were carefully written to avoid it, and this is just the most obvious case I know about.

Comment: @Grapejuice123 -Ofast turns on O3. So it is faster than no optimisations.

Comment: @zwol thanks for pointing out. I made changes.